React Transition Not Working When Conditional Rendering Based on State Change
I have a toggle button to change the boolean state. when the state is toggled i want one particular block to appear/disappear with a transition. but the transition is not working. is there anything i'm missing?
//Imports
const DriversDetails= () => {
    const [driversDiscount,setDriversDiscount]=useState(false)
  return (
   
                 <label htmlFor="" className="flex items-center gap-2 text-[#6F6464] font-semibold pb-2">
                     <ToggleButton value={driversDiscount} action={setDriversDiscount}/>
                        Do you want to offer discounts?
                      <ExclIcon/>
                 </label>   
                {driversDiscount && 
                    <div className="flex justify-between pb-4 transition-opacity duration-500 ease-in-out opacity-100">
                        <div>
                            <p className="font-semibold text-black-primary pb-1">Total amount <span className="text-[12px] text-black-light">(After discount)</span></p>
                            <p className="text-[14px] font-semibold text-black-light flex gap-2 items-center "><ToggleButton value={removeCents} action={setRemoveCents} />Remove cents</p>
                        </div>
                        <p className="text-right">
                            <span className='font-[700] text-[18px] ml-1'> $8</span>
                            <span className='text-[#151515] text-sm font-medium'>.29</span>
                        </p>
                    </div>}
   
  );
}
export default DriversDetails;


For CSS transitions to "play", the element must be in the DOM before the change of the transition happens.
When driversDiscount is false, the element is not present in the DOM. When driversDiscount changes to true, the element is present in the DOM already with opacity: 1 as applied by its opacity-100 class, so there is no opacity value change and thus no transition from transition: opacity.
When driversDiscount is true and then changed to false, the element is removed instantly, so no CSS transition has the chance to play. Furthermore, even it did have the chance to play, there would be no opacity value change and thus no transition from transition: opacity.
Here is a minimum solution to get the CSS transition working. We:

Keep the element in the DOM at all times.
Change the opacity value to 0 when driversDiscount is falsey, so that there is an opacity value change for the transition to tween.



const { useState } = React;

const ToggleButton = ({ value, action }) => (
  <button type="button" onClick={() => action(!value)}>
    {String(value)}
  </button>
);

const ExclIcon = () => 'ExclIcon';

const DriversDetails = () => {
  const [driversDiscount, setDriversDiscount] = useState(false);
  const [removeCents, setRemoveCents] = useState(false);
  
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <label
        htmlFor=""
        className="flex items-center gap-2 text-[#6F6464] font-semibold pb-2"
      >
        <ToggleButton value={driversDiscount} action={setDriversDiscount} />
        Do you want to offer discounts?
        <ExclIcon />
      </label>
      <div className={`flex justify-between pb-4 transition-opacity duration-500 ease-in-out ${driversDiscount ? '' : 'opacity-0'}`}>
        <div>
          <p className="font-semibold text-black-primary pb-1">
            Total amount{" "}
            <span className="text-[12px] text-black-light">
              (After discount)
            </span>
          </p>
          <p className="text-[14px] font-semibold text-black-light flex gap-2 items-center ">
            <ToggleButton value={removeCents} action={setRemoveCents} />
            Remove cents
          </p>
        </div>
        <p className="text-right">
          <span className="font-[700] text-[18px] ml-1"> $8</span>
          <span className="text-[#151515] text-sm font-medium">.29</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("app")).render(<DriversDetails />);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<div id="app"></div>



